# MySQL trigger set values for NEW row and update another in the same table

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I have a table that I keep track of fees for a specific item. These fees can change over time so I have two columns (startDate, endDate) with the current set of fees always having an endDate in the far future. I already have a trigger that I use to do some calculations on the new row being entered but what I also want to have happen is if I enter an item that already has an entry I want to set the previous entry's endDate to the day before the new entry's startDate and the new endDate to a predetermined far-away date. Here is the code for what I tried first:

```
CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`%`
TRIGGER `im`.`splitBeforeIns`
BEFORE INSERT ON `im`.`split`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.tcPercent = (NEW.tcOfficeFee / NEW.globalFee) * 100 , NEW.proPercent = 100 - NEW.tcPercent, NEW.endDate = 20501231;
    UPDATE im.split set endDate = ADDDATE(NEW.startDate, -1) where procKey = NEW.procKey AND endDate = 20501231;
END$$
```

The error I get is:

```
ERROR 1442: Can't update table 'split' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

Comment: Try doing your update in an AFTER INSERT trigger.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll I tried that :-( I got the same error.

Comment: The thing is that you can't explicitly update the target of your trigger from within the trigger. You might have to find another way to go about your task.

Comment: Please show the following : 1) `SHOW CREATE TABLE im.split\G` and 2) a sample INSERT command into `im.split`.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA I am not sure how this helps . . . according to the answers below, it is not possible to update another row in the same table with a trigger. Do you think it is possible?

Comment: Here is a question: Do prockey,endDate form a Unique Key in the table ?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA No, but it could. Right now I have it set to procKey and startDate. What are you thinking?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer to this might be unwelcome, but it is: You can't do that.

A Trigger can't **update another row of the same table** as the row, the trigger was called from.

The typical way to do that, is to create a stored procedure, that inserts into/Updates the target table, then updates the other row(s), all in a transaction.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting a way for me to achieve what I was going for.

Answer (score 9):

If you have a UNIQUE KEY defined on (procKey,EndDate), then perhaps you can remove the second line of the trigger. Also remove the hardcoded date from the trigger.

```
CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`%`
TRIGGER `im`.`splitBeforeIns`
BEFORE INSERT ON `im`.`split`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.tcPercent = (NEW.tcOfficeFee / NEW.globalFee) * 100 , NEW.proPercent = 100 - NEW.tcPercent;
END$$
```

and do an [*INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) like this:

```
INSERT INTO im.split ...
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
endDate = ADDDATE(startDate, -1);
```

You may also want to define endDate in im.split as follows

```
enddate DATE DEFAULT '2050-12-31'
```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get it to work, by creating a "wrapper table" which is defined with the same fields as your target table, but by using the FEDERATED storage engine. The federated server I defined to target the same mysql server/itself, so at "localhost". The trigger I then made change a row in the wrapper table. Of course you have to be very sure what you do in the trigger, to avoid a recursive loop. Also potentially the performance isn't that good; I haven't tested performance, but it has been working for years in a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

From the [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html):

> Within a stored function or trigger, it is not permitted to modify a
>   table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the
>   statement that invoked the function or trigger.

You will need to find some other way of doing what you're trying to do.