# MYSQL error 1442: Cannot update a table in a trigger/stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

Consider the table `TRADE_ORDERS`.

```
Symbol | Type | Count | Settled | Settled_count
------ | -----| ------| --------| -------------
Apple  | BUY  | 100   | NO      |  0
Apple  | BUY  | 50    | NO      |  0
```

I have written a trigger `after_trade_orders_insert` that will `AFTER INSERT` of a new row will try to settle the previous orders depending on the if there are unsettled orders.

Now if I `INSERT` into `TRADE_ORDERS` the row with values `Apple, SELL, 150`, it should settle all the bought shares. So the intended action should bring the table to below state.

**Intended Output**

```
Symbol | Type | Count | Settled | Settled_count
------ | -----| ------| --------| -------------
Apple  | BUY  | 100   | YES     |  100
Apple  | BUY  | 50    | YES     |  50
Apple  | SELL | 150   | YES     |  150
```

I understand how to write code in mysql to achieve. But when I write the code to do that in `after_trade_orders_insert`, it fails with error

> Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'NSE_FO' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.        0.055 sec

I understand what this error is and why it happens.

Question: How do I achieve the intended output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot do what we want to do - A Trigger/Stored procedure cannot update another row of the same table as the row, the trigger was called from.

How to achieve it?
From an accepted answer on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247590/mysql-trigger-set-values-for-new-row-and-update-another-in-the-same-table?answertab=votes#tab-top)

> The typical way to do that, is to create a stored procedure, that
>   inserts into/Updates the target table, then updates the other row(s),
>   all in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

you can not update recently inserted row in table by trigger so , you have to use where clause with **new** keyword.

Comment: Ok. But is it allowed for me to update any other rows of the same table?

Comment: exactly, but it can not  update newly inserted row for which you are using trigger.

Comment: If I am intending to update some other rows of the same table. How do I achieve it?

Comment: Use where clause in the trigger function.