# get updated field name and value in trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

i have one table called product

```
product_id    rate      Quantity    modified_fields
    1          100         4
    3          32          2
    5          43          1
```

so if i am updating any field in product table

suppose i am changing rate 100 to 50 then i need to set up one trigger that will update modified_fields column with rate:50(New value)

```
 product_id       rate      Quantity    modified_fields
        1          50          4         rate:50
        3          32          2
        5          43          1
```

**Edit:** What I basically need is that I need to identify which particular column was edited on an Update operation. Table can have 50 columns, and any one of them can be updated. Trigger will basically determine which column is updated, and the corresponding new value. It will then update the modified fields column with the **update column name : new value**

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You need query for trigger ?

Comment: provide query then

Comment: you can directly write simple query as UPDATE product set rate = 50, modified_fields = CONCAT('rate',':',50)  for same table, if it will be other table then trigger fine, but for same table you could use this

Comment: @VforVendettaWhat I basically need is that I need to identify which particular column was edited on an Update operation. Table can have 50 columns, and any one of them can be updated. Trigger will basically determine which column is updated, and the corresponding new value. It will then update the modified fields column with the update column name : new value

Answer (score 1):

You can get the reference of [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247590/mysql-trigger-set-values-for-new-row-and-update-another-in-the-same-table) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877732/mysql-trigger-for-updating-same-table-after-insert).

Alternatively, you can try like this,

```
UPDATE product set rate = 50, modified_fields = CONCAT('rate',':',50);
```

If it is for same table.
Trigger should be used in case of updating columns of another table.

Comment: we can't update product table after Update using trigger

Comment: once i used this before update trigger in the same table , it worked

Comment: Is it necessary to run trigger after update ? means can't we run trigger before update ?

Comment: so we can solve this above mentioned problem using before update trigger ? if yes then how?

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER update_trig BEFORE UPDATE ON product 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SET new.modified_fields=  CONCAT('rate',':',rate)
END
;

Comment: what if i am updating another field and how i will get updated value in trigger

Comment: i can't hard code trigger like this new.modified_fields= CONCAT('rate',':',rate)

Comment: Why don't you create log table to maintain each n every changes in the table, is it necessary to maintain in same table ?

Comment: And meanwhile, you can create trigger for the same

Comment: NO my requirements are different

Comment: You are using mysql with which technology ?

Comment: php with mysql db

Comment: So you can append every changes to modified_fields with whatever delimeter you want, why trigger ?

Comment: i want that automatically