# SQL Trigger update on same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

I want to create a trigger in MySQL for the following table such that if the attribute of occurrences is greater than 100 the attribute of status updates to "popular".

The name of the table is `trigger`

```
Repo_ID |Occurences |Status
1       | 50        | Normal
2       | 70        | Normal
3       | 190       | Popular
```

I've tried the following thing. It didnt work. Any suggestions?

```
CREATE TRIGGER `A` after update
 ON `trigger`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
  IF (new.occurence > 100) THEN
    SET new.STATUS = "popular";
  ELSE SET new.STATUS = "normal";
  END IF;
END
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Go through these links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247590/mysql-trigger-set-values-for-new-row-and-update-another-in-the-same-table     and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877732/mysql-trigger-for-updating-same-table-after-insert

Comment: I got this error:
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1362: Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger

Comment: @lucyF Can you add it to the question too?

Comment: Should be a before trigger

Answer (score 2):

You want a *before* update trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `A` before update ON `trigger`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    SET new.STATUS = (CASE WHEN new.occurences > 100 THEN 'popular' ELSE 'normal' END);
END;
```

I also removed the `IF` because `CASE` seems more concise.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff. I used the before update trigger and encountered a new error 

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1054: Unknown column 'occurence' in 'NEW'

Comment: @lucyF . . . That is what you wrote in your original code.  Perhaps it is `occurences` as in the sample data.